# Amazon S3 Redirect

Tags: amazon-s3, xml

Is there a way to redirect your domain which you are pointing towards S3 to your home pages? Like I am hosting my videos on Amazon S3 but if someone try to access the my s3.mywebsite.com it result in xml output, I want the user to redirect back to my home page (mywebsite.com)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you put an Amazon CloudFront distribution in front of your S3 bucket, you can define a Default root object. This could be an html containing a javascript redirect to another site.

See the [Amazon CloudFront Developer Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?DefaultRootObject.html) for more information on how to set up CloudFront and set up the root object.